# Changing the jne to je instruction causes program to generate error

Tags: binary-analysis, radare2, binary, patching

I'm trying to change the instruction from `jne` to `je`

[image: jne instruction]

I've change an instruction

```
75 0c        jne [some_location]
```

`75 0c` is a 2 jump instruction.

So, I've a chaged it to from `75 0c` to `74 0c` which is also a 2 byte `jcc` instruction.

The error:

```
./binary: 1: 00000000:: not found
/* Repeat of the same error but instead of 0000000X where is X is some number */
```

EDIT: The problem was the hex editor was filtering lines and corrupting data? I was using nvim as the hex edior

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate what tool you're using when the error occurs.

Comment: @RolfRolles It should be tool agnostic, right? Nothing here is really dependent on the tool I use. I use a disassembler to view the assembly and use a hex editor to edit the instruction.

Comment: Oh, I misread. The *program that you patched* is generating this error, not the tool that did the patching. In any case, this question is impossible to answer. We have 3 lines of assembly code and the knowledge that if you invert a jump, the program spits out a message that it didn't produce before you patched it. What answer are you looking for beyond "you altered the logic of the program, and its behavior changed as a result"?

Comment: We can help you better with more info on the binary - maybe attach it? Additionally any more details on the crash/error in the patched binary - maybe run it under a debugger?

Comment: @RolfRolles The problem was the hex editor was filtering lines and corrupting data? I switched do a new hex editor. I was using nvim and it was filtering liines

Comment: @sudhackar The problem was the hex editor was filtering lines and corrupting data? I switched do a new hex editor. I was using nvim and it was filtering liines

Comment: @user40683 You can write an answer about the hex editor and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use an hexadecimal editor with radare2. r2 is a reverse engineering framwork. It does everything.

First ensure radare2 is updated with the latest version:

```
git clone https://github.com/radareorg/radare2
sh radare2/sys/install.sh
```

Then open your program in write mode, replace NAMEOFYOURPROGRAM by the name of the program that you want to patch. Then you can overwrite the instruction:

```
radare2 -a x86 -b 32 -w NAMEOFYOUREXECUTABLE
=> s 0x1343
=> "wa jn 0x1351"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to swap a conditional jump you can use the `wao` command like this: `r2 -qc 'wao recj @ 0x1343' -w YOURPROGRAM`.

But you can also use:

- `wx 74@0x1343`
- `wai jne 0x1351@0x1343`
- `woa 01@!1`

(there are many other ways to achieve the same, pick the one you like more)